# SQL Server TempDB on Local SSDs with VMs

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2016, windows-server, tempdb

Two physical Servers in a Cluster. Multiple SQL 2016 Virtual Machines. Fibre Channel SAN Storage used for the Virtual Machine Operating System and Database Data Files. I've seen multiple sources claim that using local SSDs for the TempDB is best practice.

How should the Local Storage be presented to the Virtual Machine for the TempDB? If the Virtual Machine migrates within the cluster, it will lose the virtual hard drive. How can this best practice be implemented with the above scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the same local storage paths on both nodes for the TempDB in order for the nodes to fail over properly.

Comment: Does that mean each node has to have a VHD for each VM within the cluster? What happens if we run out of local storage, especially when most of the VHDs aren't in use on the specific node?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  You just have to manage storage the best way possible.  If you want the TempDB to reside on local storage in a cluster, matching the paths on all nodes is the only way for this to work.